# Why is $M$ bounded in $\mathscr L^2$ iff $E[\lim A_n] < \infty$?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, probability-theory, measure-theory, martingales

Probability with Martingales:

---

[image]

---

[image]

---

About $(c)$

My understanding is that $(c)$ is equivalent to:

$$\sup E[A_n] < \infty \iff E[\lim A_n] < \infty$$

Why is that so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$E[\lim A_n] = \lim E[A_n]\ \text{by MCT}$$

$$= \sup E[A_n] \ \because \ P(A_n \le A_{n+1}) = 1 \ \forall \ n \ \because \ P(A_n \le A_{n+1} \ \forall \ n) = 1$$