# Prove $M_{S(k) \wedge n}$ is bounded in $\mathscr L^2$

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory, martingales, stopping-times

Probability with Martingales:

---

[image]

---

To prove $$\sup E[M_{S(k) \wedge n}^2] < \infty,$$ how can we use [12.12c](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1818111/why-is-m-bounded-in-mathscr-l2-iff-e-lim-a-n-infty)? There aren't any stopping times there.

Comment: Apply 12.12.c to the stopped process $M^{S(k)}$, which is also a martingale.

Comment: @JohnDawkins and I guess finite expectation follows from being bounded? How's my attempt?

Comment: Your argument is fine.

Comment: @JohnDawkins Thanks XD post as answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\sup E[M_{S(k) \wedge n}^2]$$

$$ = \sup (E[N_{S(k) \wedge n}] + E[A_{S(k) \wedge n}])$$

$$ \le \sup (E[N_{S(k) \wedge n}]) + \sup(E[A_{S(k) \wedge n}])$$

Since $S(k)$ is a stopping time and $N$ is a martingale, we have

$$E[N_{S(k) \wedge n}] = E[N_{n}] (= 0)$$

We have $E[A_{S(k) \wedge n}] \le E[k] = k$

Thus,

$$\sup E[M_{S(k) \wedge n}^2] \le \sup (E[N_{S(k) \wedge n}]) + \sup(E[A_{S(k) \wedge n}]) = \sup(0) + \sup(k) = 0 + k = k < \infty$$